# c++. possible to do this without getting error: 'was not declared in this scope'

Tags: c++, variables, if-statement, declaration

c++. Is it possible to do this?

```
if (x>3)
 int foo=10
else
 long foo=10
```

without getting error:

> was not declared in this scope

Comment: What are you trying to do? Have a specific issue?

Comment: Please show the code that generates that error.

Comment: You **can not** do what you propose. The scope of the variables are the `if` and the `else` respectively. Variables are strongly typed within each scope in C++ - you're trying to break that. Probably this is an [xy](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) question.

Comment: Also, you can not declare a variable inside an if-statement/else-statement and use it in the code outside that statement.

Comment: XY problem, again. What is the bigger picture? what do you want to achieve with that?

Answer (score 8):

Yes you can, using [`std::variant`<sup>C++17</sup>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) or `boost::variant`.

```
std::variant<int, long> foo;

if(x > 3)
    foo = 10;
else
    foo = long(10);
```

And then access `foo` like so:

```
if(auto value = std::get_if<int>(&foo))
    std::cout << "foo is int: " << *value << '\n'; 
else {
    long value = std::get<long>(foo);
    std::cout << "foo is long: " << value << '\n'; 
}
```

I don't know why you would want to do that though. A `long` is guaranteed to be able to hold all `int` values so you can just make `foo` of type `long`, and avoid `std::variant` altogether.

Comment: Nice answer, learned something. Not exactly what he asks but probably what he meant.

Answer (score 2):

no you cannot because that variable `x` is scoped inside the if block so you cannot see it from outside:

```
int main()
{
    if(!x)
        int value = 100;
    else
        double value = 5.57; 

    cout << value << endl; // values is scoped to if statement or else's so it will be destructed

    // this example is like what you have above
    for(;;)
    {
        int a = 77;
        if(a)
            break;
    }

    cout << a << endl; // error a is undeclared identifier

    return 0;
}
```